can't import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDev
I am working on a project and I am trying to import "org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDevs"
But when I import "org.hibernate.annotations.Type;" it does import it.
and if I hover over the TypeDev it says "cannot resolve symbol "TypeDev""
I tried asking chatgpt and but the solutions it gave me didn't help at all.
it told me to implement the following dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.3.Final</version> <!-- Replace with your Hibernate version -->
</dependency>

and it does not work.
